# Error when selecting values with like and not like MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sql-like

I'm trying to get every name from students, that contains a space character but doesn't contain "der"

When i try to do

```
select * from students where name like "% %" and not like "% der %
```

it makes this error: 
"SELECT" is no valid input at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH

Im using MySql Workbench. It works until i put in "and not like" in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put column name before not like

```
select * from students where name like "% %" and name not like "% der %
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below- you've to put column name before `not like` operator also literal will be like `'% der %'`

```
select * from students where name like '% %' and name not like '% der %'
```